# Is it possible to directly access values ​stored in Prometheus from React?

Tags: reactjs, prometheus

I'm implementing a statistics chart in `React`. Data used for statistics is stored in `Prometheus`.

I want to collect the number of http request successes/errors during a specific period and display them through `React`'s `recharts` library.

I wonder if I can get the value directly from `Prometheus`, or if I have to use `Grafana` to get the refined data.

In general, when drawing statistical charts directly (non-real-time), is it possible to get values ​​directly from `Prometheus`?

Comment: Surely you can get data directly from Prometheus: [it has API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) for this. Is that what you were looking for? And what do you mean by "refined" data?